# How to get an array which is the value of a Dictionary key in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

My data is structured like this:

`var songs = [String: [Song]]()`

It is a dictionary of which the keys are strings and the values are arrays. I'm basically sorting songs by name alphabetically so I can distribute them by sections in my TableView.

I'd like to get the song name like this:

`var sectionTitle = self.tableView(tableView, titleForHeaderInSection: indexPath.section) as String!
var songName = songs[sectionTitle][indexPath.row] as String` (The error is in this line)

But XCode throws an error and says that `String is not convertible to DictinoaryIndex<String, [(Song)]>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is that Swift dictionary lookups by key return an optional – the reason being, the key might not be in the dictionary.

So you need to unwrap the optional in some fashion (that is, check the key was valid).

Try the following:

```
if let songName = songs[sectionTitle]?[indexPath.row] {
    // use songName
}
else {
    // possibly log an error
}
```

You’re also a little exposed to the risk of an index out of bound error as well, which (if you’re using Xcode 6.3) you can guard against like this:

```
if let songList = songs[sectionTitle] where songList.count < indexPath.row {
    let song = songList[indexPathrow]

}
```

Generally speaking, you should spend some time learning about optionals and techniques for unwrapping them, instead of resorting to `as` and `!` so much – your app will crash randomly if you find yourself unwrapping nils by accident like this.

Comment: This worked! I prefer to avoid the whole `if` thing. I implemented it like this: `selectedSong = songs[sectionTitle]?[indexPath!.row] as Song!`. Is there any problem with this approach?

Comment: Yes, the problem is if your code ever looks up a value that isn’t in the dictionary, your app will abort.  Generally it’s much better to use `if` than not.  Avoid `!` unless absolutely necessary.  Even when you think it’s safe, it might not be, and if you get into the habit of it, you’ll often use it when it isn’t completely safe.

Comment: If you really want to force the unwrap, you can `songs[sectionTitle]![indexPath.row]` and leave off the `as String!` part.  But like I say, better to use `if`.  Even if you want an assertion failure in case of a bad lookup, you can write a more meaningful error message in an assertion in the else rather than the rather enigmatic "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value” you’ll get back with a force-unwrap.

Comment: Thank you! In the name of good practices, I'll start to use the `if`. Thanks for the advice!